# tool to help understand project?

Tags: project

I have big  project (not mine) in java EE , at first when I looked at it there were many many classes, when I try to understand a method of class there is another class which calls method in it and again and again, It's really hard to understand the code (there is no documentation) is there any tool to help me ?

Comment: I've always been told that if someone (Obviously a developer) can't understand a piece of code without documentation it has been poorly implemented. The fact that it has no documentation anyway says to me that it has been poorly implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't really any tools to help with this, the most that you can hope is that someone created a UML Doc for the code you're viewing. However, as this is not the case, the best place to start is at the main method and slowly traverse the setup. I find that it helps to keep notes and diagrams, describing (functionally) what things do and in what order they happen.